# Triggering a macro when a specific sheet is selected - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I trigger macro `doAction` when anybody clicks on sheet `targetSheet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

[`onSelectionEvent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) works on sheet change.

---

Currently, There is no trigger for sheet selection available on Google apps script. Therefore you cannot do that.

Comment: Really? Thank you anyway!